# Rotating markers for points in Tilemill along direction of a way

Tags: coordinate-system, tilemill, markers

I have designed a simple marker to represent pedestrian crossings, which in OpenStreetMap data are represented as nodes (points) along the way (line). I want to rotate the marker to follow the line it sits on. But I can't see a way to do that.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you are using PostGIS data source. For CartoCSS, use `marker-transform: rotate([angle], 0, 0);`. The hard part is adding that angle column to the table. To do that, add a column to your SQL query, which looks like this:

```
(
  select degrees(ST_Azimuth(ST_StartPoint(inter), ST_EndPoint(inter)))
  from (
    select ST_Intersection(r.way, ST_Buffer(p.way, 100)) as inter
    from planet_osm_line r
    where r.highway is not null and ST_Contains(r.way, p.way)
    limit 1
  ) rr
) as angle
```

I've made this query in this window and hasn't tested it, so there may be bugs. It is based on railway station marker rotation from [veloroad style](https://github.com/Zverik/veloroad).

Comment: I've gone with this:

`( SELECT way, highway, (
  select degrees(ST_Azimuth(ST_StartPoint(inter), ST_EndPoint(inter)))
  from (
    select ST_Intersection(r.way, ST_Buffer(p.way, 100)) as inter
    from planet_osm_line r
    where r.highway in ('primary','secondary') and r.way && ST_Buffer(p.way, 100) order by ST_Distance(r.way, p.way)
    limit 1
  ) rr
) as angle
 FROM planet_osm_point p WHERE highway IN ('bus_stop', 'crossing', 'traffic_signals' ) ) AS data`

Comment: I've got a further challenge... this can rotate pedestrian crossings to be in line with the road. What about rotating bus stop markers so that they point 'into' the road they relate to? See this for example: http://www.moma.org/interactives/exhibitions/2011/talktome/assets/TTM_131a-large.jpg The query you gave me can rotate all bus stops so they are at ninety degrees to the way, but not to ensure the point of the marker is pointing in to the way.

Comment: Try `ST_Azimuth(p.way, ST_ClosestPoint(inter, p.way))`.